# Use Case - Multiple Actors/Use Cases

Tags: uml, diagram, actor, use-case

Got a use case diagram question regarding parent child use cases.

**Scenario**

The parent use case is Create New Product and this has say 4 mandatory child use cases e.g. Model Product, Price Product, Approve Product etc.

The parent use case is always initiated by one actor.  The same actor has an association with 2 of the 4 child use cases, whilst another 2 actors have the association with the other 4.  How do I depict this digramatically.  Do I show the four child connected to the parent use case using the <<include>> relationship and show the actors linked directly to the child use cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As your problem statement is quite unclear, I will make the following assumptions. Please confirm/correct them:

- By "parent-child UC" you actually mean sequencial execution. A Product must first be created, then modelled, then proced, etc.
- One actor (Product creator on my diagram) executes always the "Create new product" and 2 more, while other actors (Actor1, Actor2) use the 4 UC (other than Create).

If so, the point here is to establish the **workflow** (UC order of execution) and **user permissions**. Permissions are easily shown using associations between actors and UCs.

Workflow is not directly depicted on a UC diagram. You should not use relationships between UCs to indicate their sequence (although there is a way). I recommend two actions to achieve what you want to achieve:

1. Use pre and postconditions for each UC to mark the legal sequences (see the diagram for an example and eventually an UML book to understand the concept pre and postcondition)
2. Draw an additional activity diagram to show the overall workflow. You can even trace activities to UCs (graphically or descriptevly) to show which UC implements which activity

This would be the corresponding use case model:
[image]

And here is an example of an activity:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I think I will need to remodel my diagrams.  My aim isn't to show workflow but effectively to show all Use Cases from a Level 1 downwards perspective.  Therefore, my line of thinking was as follows. High level (Level 1) use case is "Create Product".  The subsequent (Level 2) use cases would always have to be invoked from Level 1.  What I might do is break down a single large and complex use case diagram into smaller individual diagrams e.g. my use case diagram will be "Create New Product" (Level 1 use case) or "Market Product" etc.